# Корректный вывод данных json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Я получаю на вход json файл с определенными данными. Из этого json файла мне надо получать значения и выводить их, но некоторые поля файла не определены и выводиться в виде "None". Как сделать чтобы None заменить на "Не указано" ?
Ниже приведен пример получения файлов и вытаскивание с файла необходимых полей.

```
 " Личные данные: \n"
    "Имя: %s \n" % qwe.json()["name"] +
    "Фамилия: %s \n" % qwe.json()["surname"] +
    "О себе: %s \n" % qwe.json()["about"] +
    "Работа: %s \n\n\n" % qwe.json()["status"] +
    " Контактные данные:\n"
    "email: %s \n" % qwe.json()["contactDetails"]["email"] +
    "Телефон: %s \n" % qwe.json()["contactDetails"]["phone"] +
    "VK: %s \n" % qwe.json()["contactDetails"]["vkontakte"] +
    "facebook: %s \n" % qwe.json()["contactDetails"]["facebook"] +
    "instagram: %s \n" % qwe.json()["contactDetails"]["instagram"]+ 
    "Адрес: %s, " % qwe.json()["address"]["region"] + "г. " + qwe.json() 
    ["address"]["city"] + ", " + qwe.json()["address"]["street"] + ", кв." + 
    qwe.json()["address"]["house"] + "\n\n\n" +
    " Образование: \n" +
   "Институт: %s \n" % qwe.json()["jobSeekerEducations"][0]["institution"] +
   "Специальность: %s \n" % qwe.json()["jobSeekerEducations"][0]["specialty"] +
   "Тип образования: %s \n" % qwe.json()["jobSeekerEducations"][0]["education"] 
   +
   "Дата начала: %s \n" % qwe.json()["jobSeekerEducations"][0]["dateStart"] +
   "Дата окончания: %s \n\n\n" % qwe.json()["jobSeekerEducations"][0 
   ["dateReceiving"] +
   " Компетенции: \n" + "\n".join(arrey) + "\n\n\n" +
   " Опыт работы: \n" +
   "Компания: %s \n" % qwe.json()["jobApplicantSet"][0]["employer"] +
   "Позиция: %s \n" % qwe.json()["jobApplicantSet"][0]["position"] +
   "Дата начала работы: %s \n" % qwe.json()["jobApplicantSet"][0]["startDate"] 
   +
   "Дата окончания работы: %s \n" % qwe.json()["jobApplicantSet"][0] 
   ["stopDate"]
```

Comment: создайте функцию которая будет возвращать `return qwe.json()[value] or "Не указано"`

Comment: либо `.replace("None", "Не указано")`